# Why won't taxonomy list sort alphabetically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Running Drupal 7.28, I've created a taxonomy vocab 'care centers' with a list of terms with care center names 'Atlanta''Boston''Cincinnati' 'Detroit' etc. Problem: Care centers were entered in random order 'Detroit' 'Boston' 'Atlanta' 'Cincinnati', when I click on 'Reset to Alphabetical' they reorder alphabetically, but when I save, they go back to order entered. People self-select their care center from a drop down list populated by the taxonomy, would help if it were displayed alphabetical.

How do I get the list to sort and display alphabetical?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried with "Show row weights", it looks like a javascript problem; adding the weight manually will give you some hint about that problem.

Comment: thanks, tried resetting all the row weights to 0, when I click save they go back to the original row weights. Realize I imported the list of care centers using taxonomy manager, wonder if that's somehow locking the order...